# Restricting access from only 3 domains in my htaccess fle - SetEnvIf Referer

Tags: .htaccess

Hi so i have the below working:

```
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://sub\.site1\.com/yvvl/Portal/" local_referral
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://sub\.site2\.com/yvvl/Portal/" auth_referral
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://sub\.site3\.com/yvvl/Portal/" authC_referral
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=local_referral
Allow from env=auth_referral
Allow from env=authC_referral
```

what i dont know how to do is wildcard it so anything from those 3 domains will be accepted my preg is not good at all

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove everything after the `.com`:

```
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://sub\.site1\.com/" local_referral
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://sub\.site2\.com/" auth_referral
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://sub\.site3\.com/" authC_referral
```

Since there's no fence-post for the end of the referer (indicated by the `$` character) that will match anything that *starts with* `http://sub.site1.com/` etc.

Comment: thank you for the reply, what about any sub domain of the main URL?